# I have imported csv into table using php but facing in problem?

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I am facing this problem in excel file the value is 1.93E+11  and It is not converted into 193000000000 when I import the csv to MYSQL table. It's value remain the same as 1.93E+11

How can I do it to convert it my code is

```
  if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

    while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 58000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT into excel ()
               values ('" . $column[0] . "','" . $column[1] . "')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

        if (! empty($result)) {
            $type = "success";
            $message = "CSV Data Imported into the Database";
```

Comment: ... and this is one of the reasons I dislike Excel ... try [Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) instead, you'll have fewer problems (of this sort anyway)

Comment: Is there any thing in php through I can convert it to full form like 193000000000

Comment: I'd be worried about the fact that the number is too big to fit into an `INT(11) UNSIGNED` field in the database to be honest... you could use the non-standard `BIGINT` data type or, since PHP is loosely typed, just store it as text in the database then juggle the type in the application as per h00ligan's answer. Make sure you're using a 64-bit version of PHP though, otherwise (again) the number will be too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can typecast it to a float:

```
$value = (float) $column[1];
```

To be sure that you actually have a floating point number you can try checking like this

```
if (is_numeric($column[1]) && !is_int($column[1])) {
    $value = (float) $column[1];
}
```